# Deserialize newline delimited string from JSON to java POJO with Jersey

Tags: java, json, string, jackson, jersey-2.0

We're using Jersey to map POJO's from a JSON service. One of the datapoints returned is a string containing various titles of correspondence delimited with the newline character (\n). Currently I'm accepting this as a string and doing all kinds of string manipulations to get to the correct piece.

Is there a way (in the default jersey/jackson setup) to serialize this string to an array for example, where each \n segment indicates a new entry in the array?

example string:

```
"Letter to the king\nLetter to the Queen\nBills"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "deserialize"?

Comment: @Jan you're right. I'm always switching those up

Comment: @irongollem [Jackson Data Format CSV](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text)
 may be helpful in your case